# Remove NSNotificationCenter observer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am detecting the showing/hiding of the keyboard by adding this code in the ViewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification 
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

At some point though I want to remove these observers, without calling

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

because this removes all observers, and I have other observers that I don't want to be removed. How can I remove only those two??

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification 
                                              object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                              object:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `removeObserver:name:object:` method of `NSNotificationCentre` as described [in the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/removeObserver%3aname%3aobject%3a), to remove an observer for a particular notification name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[NsNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil]`